# Sending CURL command using Objective-C for an OS X App

Tags: objective-c, macos, parsing, curl

I'm trying to integrate the Parse API into an OS X app I'm doing for school. The App should send a Push notification, so I figured I would use the REST API from Parse to accomplish this.

The code below is the example CURL code Parse provides for sending a notification.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "channels": [
          "Giants",
          "Mets"
        ],
        "data": {
          "alert": "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

What would be the Objective-C equivalent for accomplishing the past CURL code? Or what do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [URL-handling APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) in the Foundation framework. Here's an example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/push"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[request addValue:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:@"{\"channels\": [\"Giants\",\"Mets\"], \"data\": {\"alert\": \"The Giants won against the Mets 2-3.\"}}"];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And then implement the methods required by the [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) protocol.